# Problem with an image in a single page application

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a single page application, with no routes.
I am using bootstrap, and I have a background image but it is distorting because of the content.

This is my frontend:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700&display=swap');
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    background-image: url('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muspikess.appspot.com/o/website%2Folena-sergienko-3kvB1VldPBI-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=94b21b44-82fc-47a3-8e44-85a160e8c268');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.dark-color {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #333;
}

.dark-color:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #333;
    border-color: #333;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    color: #55acee;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="mt-4">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
                    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muspikess.appspot.com/o/website%2Fbrand.png?alt=media&token=22d368f7-26eb-4d2a-804d-86908fe5edee" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="mr-5" href="https://twitter.com/muspikesss">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row ml-5">
                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <h2>Who we are?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quos expedita dicta culpa velit alias, esse sit omnis in delectus quod, quas suscipit cumque tempora illum ipsam, ex quae labore.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ml-5">
                <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                    <h2>How to participate?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quos expedita dicta culpa velit alias, esse sit omnis in delectus quod, quas suscipit cumque tempora illum ipsam, ex quae labore.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
        </div>
    </main>


</body>
```

And I am getting this:

[image]

As you can see, the clock is deformed.

And my image has no problem

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock is deformed because you're applying the background image to both the `html` and `body` element. You can fix it by applying the background image only to the `body` element, e.g.

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muspikess.appspot.com/o/website%2Folena-sergienko-3kvB1VldPBI-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=94b21b44-82fc-47a3-8e44-85a160e8c268');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```